# How to determine which modules needed for licensing FFmpeg as part of an app

Tags: ffmpeg, license

I developed an app that uses `ffmpeg` for some simple muxing, which I am going to sell. I contacted MPEG LA about licensing, and they said I the license I need depends on which codecs I use.

Is there any way to determine which codecs/libraries are actually being used by a particular `ffmpeg` command?

If not, is there any way to temporarily disable/enable options to see if they are required for a given operation?

FWIW, my operation doesn't re-encode anything. It uses `c:v copy` and `c:a copy` with a `map` function to re-arrange audio tracks. In some cases it converts `pcm_s24be` to `pcm_s24le`.

Comment: I know nothing of MPEG LA licensing, but you can configure ffmpeg to support only certain components. What formats are you intending to support? *"my operation doesn't re-encode anything... In some cases it converts `pcm_s24be` to `pcm_s24le`"*. Sounds like a contradiction. Which cases? Also, it seems that you intend to distribute ffmpeg, so you have to comply with the (L)GPL (which one depends on how you configure ffmpeg).

Comment: I meant doesn't re-encode video. The PCM conversion is the one thing that might sometimes be needed. I'm working with MXF containers using Avid DNxHD codec. I was trying to avoid re-compiling multiple times just to figure out which libraries are needed.

Comment: Yeah I don't think it's about what command you app uses but the build of ffmpeg that your app bundle. I guess `ffmpeg -codecs` and `ffmpeg -formats` gives at least part of the information you need.

Answer (score 1):

You really need a lawyer. The licensing is very complex. For example, if you’re distributing h.264 video, and the video is monetized (including just to cover costs) you need a license if you transit more that a minimum amount of video minutes. It doesn’t matter if you reencode or not.

And every codec (both audio and video) have different requirements.

Any answer other than, “figure out exactly what codecs you want/need to support, and call a lawyer” is wrong.